# What does Android use to make its sensor type TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR?

Tags: gyroscope, android-sensors

Which of the accelerometer, gyroscope, and compass are being used for this "sensor" Rotation_Vector?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, after some test, "I think" accel + magneto + gyro + compass maybe

I can assume that because the YAW doesn't drift and it's quite accurate near magneticfield pertubation